# three dimensional and multitype array (or probably list?)

Tags: c#

I have a question which is probably something simple but I don't know how to resolve...

I have a class with three different arrays:

```
public Datetime[] Moment { get; set; }
public object Value { get; set; }
public int[] State { get; set; }
```

How could I achieve to create an object with these three arrays but like an array of arrays? Imagine I have two object with these data

```json
{
   "Moment":[
      "2021-11-15T13:12:45.273Z"
   ],
   "Value":[
      2.166
   ],
   "State":[
      1
   ]
}
```

AND

```json
{
   "Moment":[
      "2021-11-15T13:12:45.273Z"
   ],
   "Value":[
      1.548
   ],
   "State":[
      2
   ]
}
```

What I want to do is something like these:

```json
{
   "ms":[
      "2021-11-15T13:12:45.273Z",
      "2021-11-15T13:12:45.273Z"
   ],
   "vs":[
      2.166,
      1.548
   ],
   "ss":[
      1,
      2
   ]
}
```

I want to do this indifferently of the number of objects or the lenght of the arrays. I need it to be dynamic. Some help?

Comment: I'm not sure i truly understand the problem or what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Isn't it better to create an array with multiple of these classes?

Comment: Assuming I understand the question you could just bind all these different types together in a Tuple and then have a single array (or list) to hold them all.

Comment: @thegeneral Basically I want to merge the arrays of my instances to make a new object with all data. My major problem is with the Value property because is an object and if I cannot Concat of loop with foreach.

Comment: @steven can you make an example? I'm still new at coding and I'm kinda lost with this

Comment: @zohar-peled can you make an example?

Answer (score 2):

I prefer going with a list of classes.

The class you mentioned, is unnamed, so I'm just calling it `Class` for this example. Keep in mind to rename the `Class` to the class where your arrays are.

Your question is also tagged `c#`, so the code written is with that language in mind:

```
List<Class> list = new List<Class>();
list.Add(new Class() { moment = "2021-11-15T13:12:45.273Z", Value = 2.166, State = 1};
list.Add(new Class() { moment = "2021-11-15T13:12:45.273Z", Value = 1.548, State = 2};
```

Calling the class will work similair with arrays, like `list[0]`.
The `moment`, `Value` and `State` is stored within that `list[0]`.

Reminder that this is just an example for simple classes. Larger and complex classes may require a different setup, depending on the context.